# How prove Matrices A and B inertia index are equality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be Hermitian matrices,and the real eigenvalues such that:$Re{(\lambda(AB))}\ge 0$.

Show that
Matrices A and B inertia index  are equality.

Comment: What is the inertia index of a matrix?

Comment: Thank you ,You can  see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_inertia

Comment: People are lazy. You might increase the chance of getting an answer if you make the question self-contained by including the definition. Also by indicating where the question comes from, what progress you made on it, where you get stuck, and so on.